# How to apply only the first names from a list with full names to a new list using a recursive function

Tags: python, string, list, function, recursion

I have been trying to find a method to delete the last names and append the first names to a new list using this recursive function.

```
nameList = ['Julia Truong', 'Chen Wu', 'Jebb Castro', 'Ron Kenndey', 'X Y']

def convertName(nameList):
    if nameList == []:
        return [] 
 else:
    head = nameList[0:1]
    rest = nameList[1:]
    return head + convertName(rest)
 print(convertName(nameList))
```

Comment: Your whitespace is a bit messed up. WHat did you mean? What ahppens? What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you need recursive function for that.

```
new_list = [name.split()[0] for name in nameList]
```

---

EDIT:
Okay if it HAS TO be recursive function, then this works:

```
 def convertName(nameList):
      if nameList == []:
          return []
      elif len(nameList) == 1:
          return [nameList[0].split()[0]]
      else:
          head = nameList[:1]
          rest = nameList[1:]
          print('head {}, rest {}'.format(head, rest))
          return convertName(head)+convertName(rest)
```

The output is then like this:

```
 >>> print(convertName(nameList))
    head ['Julia Truong'], rest ['Chen Wu', 'Jebb Castro', 'Ron Kenndey', 'X Y']
    head ['Chen Wu'], rest ['Jebb Castro', 'Ron Kenndey', 'X Y']
    head ['Jebb Castro'], rest ['Ron Kenndey', 'X Y']
    head ['Ron Kenndey'], rest ['X Y']
    ['Julia', 'Chen', 'Jebb', 'Ron', 'X']
```

Of course you can delete `print` inside the function - I left it there to show you how it works, since it's exam review. I'm still feeling like this is very unpythonic and I would really prefer list comprehension here.

Comment: I need to use a recursive function.

Comment: Why is there need for recursive function? Is it some homework assignment?

Comment: It is a review question for my final exam, which covers recursion.

Comment: Check edit. If it's satysfying mark as done, please.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I developed and it works fine.

```
def convertNames(nameList):
    if nameList==[]:
        return []
else:
    head = nameList[0:1]
    rest = nameList[1:]
    head = head[0].split(' ')
    head.remove(head[1])
    return head + convertNames(rest)
print(convertNames(['Julia Truong','Chen Wu','Jeb Castro','Ron Kennedy','X Y']))
```

Comment: It is not really recursive, you assume that nameList always looks the same etc.. Check my edited answer for fully recursive version.